# How to understand reduceByKey(_:::_) in Spark Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I can't understand the example of spark with scala

```
val result = rdd.map(x => ((x._1, x._2), List(x._3)).reduceByKey(_:::_)
```

Comment: What part of all that you do not understand? And what you do understand?

Answer (score 2):

1. `:::` is a method for concatenating two Scala `List`s.  For example:

   ```
   List(1, 2) ::: List(3)  // List(1, 2, 3)
   ```
2. `_ ::: _` is a shortcut for the binary function `(l1, l2) => l1 ::: l2`
3. Given a PairRDD (i.e. RDD[(K, V)]), method [`reduceByKey`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.0/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions@reduceByKey(func:(V,V)=%3EV):org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD%5B(K,V)%5D) takes a function `(V, V) => V` to perform reduction on values of type `V` for each key of type `K`.
4. With a PairRDD of type RDD[(K, List[U])], one can perform a `(l1, l2) => l1 ::: l2` reduction on the `List[U]` values for each key, as shown in the following example:

   ```
   val rdd = sc.parallelize(Seq(
     ('x', 1, "a"),
     ('x', 1, "b"),
     ('y', 2, "c"),
     ('y', 2, "d"),
     ('y', 2, "e")
   ))

   val pairRDD = rdd.map(r => ((r._1, r._2), List(r._3)))  // RDD[((Char, Int), List[String])]

   val result = pairRDD.reduceByKey(_ ::: _)

   result.collect
   // Array[((Char, Int), List[String])] = Array(
   //   ((y, 2), List(c, d, e)),
   //   ((x, 1), List(a, b))
   // )
   ```